# Rendering a hash inside a JSON file with Ruby and ERB ('=>' notation)

Tags: ruby, json, hash, erb

I am trying to render a JSON template using ERB, unfortunately, due to the '=>' hash notation, it's not as simple as it was using Python.
Here's a short example:

```
  require 'erb'

  h = Hash.new
  h["first"] = "First"
  h["second"] = "Second"

  template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  {
    "key": "value",
    "foo": 1,
    "Hash": <%= h %>,
    "bar": 2
  }
  EOF

  puts template.result(binding)
```

This code will produce this output:

```
  {
    "key": "value",
    "foo": 1,
    "Hash": {"first"=>"First", "second"=>"Second"},
    "bar": 2
  }
```

Converting the '=>' notation to colons will result in a valid json file.
Is there a way to so using Ruby/ERB that I'm no aware of (except for printing keys, values and characters separately)? Or should run a substitution on my generated json files?

I feel like I'm missing the obvious solution

Comment: Why use ERB for this at all? Why don't you build a nested hash and `to_json` it?

Comment: I'm not sure I have an intelligent answer to that! I'll put a bit of thought into it, if it really doesn't benefit me I'll just remove all redundancy. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like :

```
require 'erb'
require 'json'

h = Hash.new
h["first"] = "First"
h["second"] = "Second"

template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  {
    "key": "value",
    "foo": 1,
    "Hash": <%= h.to_json %>,
    "bar": 2
  }
EOF

puts template.result(binding)
```

**output**

```
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby a.rb
  {
    "key": "value",
    "foo": 1,
    "Hash": {"first":"First","second":"Second"},
    "bar": 2
  }
[arup@Ruby]$
```

Comment: I knew it had to be that simple:) Thanks!